# Sandboxes in Partner Developer Org?

Tags: environment-hub

Our company just created a Salesforce Partner Developer Org. What if we want to create Sandboxes? Also, it is not clear to me if i can create from this org, an environment hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partner developer orgs are created from environment hub. They are basically normal developer orgs with more licenses and storage limit.

You can only create sandboxes from production orgs (Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Database.com ).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_create.htm&type=5